# postgres data retention in Kubernetes minikube

Tags: postgresql, minikube

I am trying to deploy postgres with persistent volume on my minikube instance. I have mounted the the volume(hostpath) using the PVC but I don't see the data retention of the postgres tables. I tried to touch a file in shared directory in the pod and found it was retained which means volume is retained between deployments but why postgres table. Thanks for any insights

Here is my postgres deployment yaml

`apiVersion:   extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dbapp-deployment
  labels:
    app: dbapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dbapp
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      namespace: default
      labels:
        app: dbapp
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: dbapp
          image: xxxxx/dbapp:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: pvc001
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgres/data
      volumes:
        - name: pvc001
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: pvc001`


`$ kubectl get pvc
NAME     STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
pvc001   Bound    pvc-29320475-37dc-11e9-8a82-080027218780   1Gi        RWX            standard       29m`

Comment: Are you certain the path is correct? Often there is a version number in the path. You can determine the path by executing the following query `show data_directory;`

Comment: @Eelke I think so because I can see the manually created file in that directory but when somehow the PG tables and data inside it is not retained. I should also mention at the start of my container I am running a sql to create tables in case it doesn't already exist by placing it under /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/  in the container

Comment: What I'm saying is that I suspect that postgresql is not storing it's data in `/var/lib/postgres/data`.